# Скрипт не запускается при повторном нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Если ввести неправильно данные,то выводит нужное сообщение об ошибке,но когда редактирую данные и ввожу правильно,скрипт уже не запускается.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

              $('#log-button').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = new FormData($('#loginForm')[0]);

                $.ajax({
                  url: "ajax-login.php",
                    type: "POST",
                     data:data,
                     processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                        var msg = "";
                        var succsess='<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url='+ document.location.origin + '/setSession.php">';
                      if (data === 'ok') {
                        $("#log-message").html(succsess);

                      }
                      else {
                        msg = "Invalid username or password!";

                      }
                      $("#log-message").html(msg);
                   }
               });
             });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Что в console пишет?

Comment: Консоль чиста...ошибок нет

Comment: Попробуйте добавить вывод в консоле что нить, при success. И посмотреть Вы вообще попадает в этот блок при повторной отправке запроса или нет.

Comment: Нет ,при втором нажатии он заходит в это условие.

Comment: Тогда посмотрите что у Вас приходит в data. Потому как если Вы попадаете в этот блок и условие у вас верно, то все должно отобразится.

Comment: дело в обработчике. Извиняюсь